# Magento creating a odbc connection

Tags: magento

I need to connect to a mssql database using magento. If it is a mySql database, we used to connect using below code:

```
<test_database>
                <connection>
                    <host></host>
                    <username></username>
                    <password></password>
                    <dbname></dbname>
                    <model></model>
                    <type></type>
                    <active></active>
                </connection>
            </test_database>
```

Is there any way of creating a connection as above using odbc?

Can anyone help me please.

Thank You.

Comment: Does this help? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73735/256

Comment: Or this? http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-do-i-install-magento-with-a-ms-sql-server-2008-database-63-nbsp--82533.html

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. i went through http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-do-i-install-magento-with-a-ms-sql-server-2008-database-63-nbsp--82533.html. But the thing is i need to use both mysql and mssql.